# Partial mocking an object for unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am using easymock for unit testing. I am trying to mock a method inside the test class.

```
ServiceEJB partialMockServiceEJB = EasyMock
            .createMockBuilder(ServiceEJB.class)
             .addMockedMethod("getStatusType")
            .createMock();
```

But it throws an error : multiple methods with the same name. I have overridden this method with different number of arguments. How can I show which of these overridden methods I want? How can I apply arguments here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in the parameter types to distinguish between overloaded methods, e.g.

```
PortalServiceEJB partialMockServiceEJB = EasyMock
            .createMockBuilder(ServiceEJB.class)
             .addMockedMethod("getStatusType", int.class)
            .createMock();
```

BTW, this is not a partial mock because there is no real object that is being partially mocked out here.  Also, you may want to consider Mockito as a mocking framework, the syntax is much nicer IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just adding int and it was not accepting it.

Comment: I know this is super old, but I was a little confused by the "this is not a partial mock" statement. In EasyMock v3.6, at least, `createMockBuilder` just calls `partialMockBuilder`, making it indeed a partial mock (again, at least >= 3.6).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `addMockedMethod()` with just the name of the metho, you use the one taking a method name and the types of its arguments as parameters: http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/internal/MockBuilder.html#addMockedMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29